# Is there a single word or phrase for something that looks/sounds wrong, but is right?

Tags: meaning

Is there a single word or phrase for something that is so commonly spelt or said incorrectly, that when said properly looks or sounds odd? E.g.

- "Company staff is expert in management..."
- Saying the champagne Moet as "Mo-waaay" (rather than "Mo-wet")

Any ideas or other examples appreciated!

Comment: Decades ago, when I was still a nuclear physicist, the mispronunciation "nucular" was so common, even among engineers, that once I found myself saying it.

Comment: "Company staff is expert in management ..." uses 'grammatical concord' and is not considered 'incorrect' (though I wouldn't use it).

Comment: @ab2 It always filled me with some trepidation that one person with his finger on the button, namely George W. Bush, couldn't even pronounce the word properly.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - sorry, should have said that my examples are the correct if unpopular way of saying those things!

Comment: This doesn't answer your single-word request question, but you might find it interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nYmWt1J4Lg

Answer (score 2):

The term **mumpsimus** is used for persistent misuse, including that due to ingrainedness:

> noun
>
> 1. adherence to or persistence in an erroneous use of language, memorization, practice, belief, etc., out of habit or obstinacy ...

{[ODO](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mumpsimus)}

Comment: +1. But I think `sumpsimus` (adherence to the _right_ form when the wrong one is more common) would be more suited to the OP's requirement.

Comment: @TusharRaj Yes, I've voted for you both - mumpsimus and sumpsimus - for you each make important points.